# Проблема с отображением в одну строку

Tags: css

Добрый день. Появилась проблема с отображение сайта на мониторах с разным расширение. В шапке есть три элемента: логотип(float:left); банер - в центре и краткая информация о сайте( float:right). Дело в том, что при увеличении страницы (CTR+ колесиком вперёд) или уменьшении всё располагается на новой строке, а должно идти в одну строку.

Comment: @angers777 у экрана - разрешение. У файла - расширение! Надоел этот ЛИКБЕЗ

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вам поможет создание контейнера, например, div, с заданием ему фиксированной  ширины(width), или задание минимальной ширины(min-width)